# How to fix Visual Studio 2013 XAML Code Snippet adds two open tag "<<" in front of the code when using TAB Shortcut?

Tags: xml, xaml, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a XAML code snippets for Xamarin Forms like this

```
<!-- Label -->
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
      <Header>
        <SnippetTypes>
          <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
          <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
        </SnippetTypes>
        <Title>Label</Title>
        <Author>Gowtham</Author>
        <Description>XAML snippet for Label</Description>
        <HelpUrl>
        </HelpUrl>
        <Shortcut>label</Shortcut>
      </Header>
      <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
          <Literal Editable="true">
            <ID>Name</ID>
            <ToolTip>Name</ToolTip>
            <Default>lblUniqueName</Default>
            <Function>
            </Function>
          </Literal>
          <Literal Editable="true">
            <ID>FontSize</ID>
            <ToolTip>FontSize for text Named Sizes such as Small, Medium, Large</ToolTip>
            <Default>Medium</Default>
            <Function>
            </Function>
          </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="XAML"><![CDATA[
                <Label x:Name="$Name$" Text="$selected$$end$" FontSize="$FontSize$"/>
                ]]>
        </Code>
      </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
```

I added a schortcut name for this `<Shortcut>label</Shortcut>`. In XamlPage When i type `<label` and pressed TAB visual studio inserts a code like this

```
<<Label x:Name="lblUniqueName" Text="" FontSize="Medium"/>
```

I want only one open tag `<` instead of the two `<<` (see above code).
How to fix this....

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

well your shortcut is

> label

and you're typing

> < label

You just have to type label and press tab.

Comment: by typing "label" inside xaml will not trigger the code snippet to insert the code.We must type a open tag in it.